# php confirm delete two onclick actions

Tags: javascript, php, html, onclick

I have a delete button, but before that I would like to ask if the person wants to delete for sure. I have 2 onclik actions, but even though I press do not delete, it deletes.

**My delete button**

```html
echo '<td style="text-align: center"><a href="#" onclick="window.open(\'/smazat-spolecnosti?id=' . $row['id'] . '\',\'_self\');return smazat()"><img height="30" width="30" src="/wp-content/themes/sparkling/smazat.png"/></a></td>';
```

**My delete confirm**

```html
function smazat(){
    return confirm('Opravdu si přejete smazat záznam?');
}
```

Comment: in such a case, your browser console is your best friend :) show us the error that you get there

Comment: Remove `return` from `smazat` function: `return confirm('Opravdu si přejete smazat záznam?');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the return of your confirm function, and stop the action, if it returns false:

```
echo '<td style="text-align: center">
      <a href="#" onclick="if (!smazat()) return false; window.open(\'/smazat-spolecnosti?id=' . $row['id'] . '\',\'_self\');">
      <img height="30" width="30" src="/wp-content/themes/sparkling/smazat.png"/>
      </a>
      </td>';
```

On click, if `smazat()` returns `false`, you have to stop the action, before to call `window.open()`, instead of calling `smazat()` after `window.open()`.